# Replace Text in Word file with Excel file content in one cell with line breaks. Replace All

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, macros

I am trying to replace a text in a Word file with the content of an Excel cell which includes line breaks. Find part has to be case sensitive. I am trying 2 different methods but they are not working in full.

In Option 1, the "Find" part is case sensitive, but when replacing, the line breaks are replaced with a square.

In Option 2, the replacement completes correctly and keep the line breaks that are included in the cell in Excel, but it is not case sensitive the part of "Find".

I have tried to combined both with no success. Any idea? I am stuck with this several days.

VBA Code Option 1:

```
Set ObjWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
ObjWord.documents.Open "C:\Example.docx"
ObjWord.Visible = True
With ObjWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "Insert Address"
            .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Range("C2")
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1           
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            .Execute Replace:=2     
    End With
```

Result Option 1: (Problem is that Line breaks are replaced with squares).

Testing Industry[]Test Road, 51, 150001 VBA, USA[]Attention: Mr. Macro[]Telephone: +1 666 666 666[]Email: macro@vba.com

VBA Code Option 2:

```
Set ObjWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
ObjWord.documents.Open "C:\Example.docx"
ObjWord.Visible = True
FindText = "Insert Address"
ReplaceText = Sheet1.Range("C2")
ObjWord.Selection.Move 6, -1 'moverse al principio del documento
ObjWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=FindText
ObjWord.Selection.Text = ReplaceText
ObjWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=FindText
```

Result Option 2 (Problem is that Find is not case sensitive):

Testing Industry

Test Road, 51, 150001 VBA, USA

Attention: Mr. Macro

Telephone: +1 666 666 666

Email: macro@vba.com

Finally, I found the way to make replace case sensitive, keeping line breaks of the cells, but now I have realized that macro stop with first find, and I need to replace all. Problem is that I cannot use "While" because Word document should remain in Track changes, so using While creates an endless loop. Any option?.

```
ObjWord.Selection.Move 6, -1 'moverse al principio del documento
ObjWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=FindText, MatchCase:=True
ObjWord.Selection.Text = ReplaceText
ObjWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=FindText, MatchCase:=True
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you use search instead of find perhaps ?

Comment: Thanks Peter. I found the way to make my option 2 case sensitive keeping line breaks when replacing. Problem now is that only replace the first item it finds, but it does not do a “replace all”. I cannot use the command “while” because Word document is in track changes.

Comment: Please write your solution into an answer and self-accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
Objword.ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = False
ObjWord.Selection.Move 6, -1 'move to the beginning of document
ObjWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=FindText, MatchCase:=True
While objword.Selection.Find.Found = True
ObjWord.Selection.Text = ReplaceText
objword.Selection.Move 6, -1
ObjWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=FindText, MatchCase:=True
Wend
objword.ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = True
```